# How to set MSPDI project properties with MPXJ library?

Tags: java, ms-project, mpxj

Hy, I am trying to create MSPDI (.xml) file using MPXJ library. I've managed to add tasks and resources but I have problem with setting project Title, etc.

I have checked examples on SourceForge and can't find how to set ProjectProperties to ProjectFile. There is only get method.

Any help or suggestions would be great :)

BR,
Vid Kraner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some example code from [`MpxjCreate.java`](https://github.com/joniles/mpxj/blob/master/src/net/sf/mpxj/sample/MpxjCreate.java) which shows properties being set:

```
  ProjectProperties properties = file.getProjectProperties();
  properties.setStartDate(df.parse("01/01/2003"));
  properties.setProjectTitle("Created by MPXJ");
  properties.setAuthor("Jon Iles");
```

Comment: Thank you very much Jon. I was looking at [link](http://mpxj.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/mpxj/src/net/sf/mpxj/sample/MpxjCreate.java?revision=1.12&view=markup) and didn't find it.